# Rspec/FactoryGirl: changes in factory not saving in test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following factory defined for a model:

```
factory :page do
  association :user, factory: :standard_user
  association :post, factory: [:short_post]
  after :create do |model|
    model.post.user = model.user
    model.save!
  end
end
```

the after create block seems to run file and the factory returns the model object with the correct/new changes however this does not persist in my test database.

ie. if i call `Page.last.post.user.id` from within my test, i still get the old user id which was assigned to the post object factory earlier before the after create block. I'm not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `after :create` callback should really be updating the `post` object, however, you're calling `save!` on your `page` object.

Try calling `model.post.save!` to save the `user_id` column on `post` directly.